How to create where condition on timestamp when querying an Azure SQL table from Databricks using spark.read
query = "(select * FROM [Source].[TimeSeriesValues] WHERE timeofday > '2024-04-02 20:59:00.0000000') as t"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('url', url).option('dbtable',query).load()

This returns no result, but running the same query in SQL:
SELECT * 
FROM [Source].[TimeSeriesValues] 
WHERE  timeofday > '2024-04-02 20:59:00.0000000'

returns 14816 rows
Code snippet
query = "(select * FROM [SourceSonwin].[TimeSeriesValues] WHERE timeofday > '2024-04-02 20:59:00') as sije"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('url', url).option('dbtable',query).load()
#df =spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=query)


df.display()

I have tried different approach on specifying the syntax, I found out that I can ad where condition on number types and it worked, but not on timestamp
